# Get route param on non-exact route match

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

In react router (4.1.2) I have the following route rendered:

```
<Route path="/organisations/:organisationId/profiles" component={MapContainer} />
```

Inside my MapContainer I get the organisationId as expected through `this.props.match.params.organisationId`

This `MapContainer` component is also rendered on any sub-routes like
`/organisations/:organisationId/profiles/:profileId`

This works as expected, but the `match` prop does not contain the `profileId`, just the `organisationId`. Which... kind of makes sense, since it it the first "match" it finds for the route. But is there any way to get the :profileId in the MapContainer when it matches a non-exact route?

Rendering two different routes with the `exact` property seems to work for my use case:

```
<Route exact path="/organisations/:organisationId/profiles" component={MapContainer} />
<Route exact path="/organisations/:organisationId/profiles/:profileId" component={MapContainer} />
```

but not sure that is the right way to do it.

Any suggestions on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
<Route path="/organisations/:organisationId/profiles/:profileId?" component={MapContainer} />
```

The `:profileId?` means that the parameter is optional. So it matches these two paths:

```
/organisations/apple/profiles
/organisations/apple/profiles/1
```